# How can I redefine a function that was exported by a powershell module

Tags: powershell

Is there a way that I can re-define a function that was exported by a module and is used by another?

Given the following folder structure:

```
C:.
│   MyScript.ps1
│
└───MyModules
    ├───Deployment
    │       Deployment.psm1
    │
    └───Logging
            Logging.psm1
```

And the following content for each file:

MyScript.ps1:

```
#Add MyModules to the module path
$cleanedModulePath = @()
$env:PSModulePath -split ";" | %{
    if( !( $_ -Match "MyModules") ){
        $cleanedModulePath += $_
    }
}
$thisDir = (Split-Path -parent $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
$moduleDir = Join-Path $thisDir "MyModules"
$cleanedModulePath += $moduleDir
$env:PSModulePath = ($cleanedModulePath -Join ";")

Import-Module Deployment -DisableNameChecking

#Neither of these manage to redefine Log-Debug - even if put before the Import
function Log-Debug{}
Set-Item -Path function:Log-Debug -Value {} -Option "AllScope,ReadOnly" -Force

Do-Something
```

Deployment.psm1:

```
Import-Module Logging -DisableNameChecking

function Do-Something {
    Log-Debug "Do-Something outputting a message via Log-Debug"
    Write-Host "Do-Something outputting a message directly"
}


Export-ModuleMember -Function Do-Something
```

and Logging.psm1:

```
function Log-Debug {
    param([string] $message)
    Write-Host $message
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Log-Debug
```

The output is:

```
C:\Temp\Deploy2>powershell .\MyScript.ps1
Do-Something outputting a message via Log-Debug
Do-Something outputting a message directly
```

but I would like it to be:

```
C:\Temp\Deploy2>powershell .\MyScript.ps1
Do-Something outputting a message directly
```

I realize that a better implementation of the Logging module would allow me to control the log level, but that's not the point of this question:  is it possible to redefine/override Log-Debug so that it is a no-op?

As noted in the source of MyScript.ps1, I have tried to redefine the function using Set-Item and just redeclaring the function to no avail....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would've guessed that simply defining an empty function with the same name should suffice. And it actually does, when both modules are imported directly in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> $modules = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
PS C:\> Get-Content "$modules\Logging\Logging.psm1"
function Log-Debug($msg) {
  Write-Host "DEBUG: $msg"
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function Log-Debug
PS C:\> Get-Content "$modules\Deployment\Deployment.psm1"
function Foo($msg) {
  Write-Output 'FOO: something'
  Log-Debug $msg
}
Export-ModuleMember Foo
PS C:\> Import-Module Logging -DisableNameChecking
PS C:\> Import-Module Deployment
PS C:\> Foo 'bar'
FOO: something
DEBUG: bar
PS C:\> function Log-Debug {}
PS C:\> Foo 'bar'
FOO: something
PS C:\> _
```

But for some reason you cannot re-define or remove a function that was imported from a module by another module (or at least I didn't find a way to do so).

However, you should be able to override the function by making use of [command precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848304.aspx). Since aliases are evaluated first, you can define an alias `Log-Debug` to a custom logging function:

```
PS C:\> $modules = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
PS C:\> Get-Content "$modules\Logging\Logging.psm1"
function Log-Debug($msg) {
  Write-Host "DEBUG: $msg"
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function Log-Debug
PS C:\> Get-Content "$modules\Deployment\Deployment.psm1"
Import-Module Logging -DisableNameChecking
function Foo($msg) {
  Write-Output 'FOO: something'
  Log-Debug $msg
}
Export-ModuleMember Foo
PS C:\> Import-Module Deployment
PS C:\> Foo 'bar'
FOO: something
DEBUG: bar
PS C:\> function Log-DebugSuperseded {}
PS C:\> Set-Alias -Name Log-Debug -Value Log-DebugSuperseded
PS C:\> Foo 'bar'
FOO: something
PS C:\> _
```

That way you can even change the logging implementation on the fly, or switch back and forth between original and custom logging function:

```
PS C:\> Foo 'bar'
FOO: something
DEBUG: bar
PS C:\> function Log-DebugSuperseded {}
PS C:\> Set-Alias -Name Log-Debug -Value Log-DebugSuperseded
PS C:\> Foo 'bar'
FOO: something
PS C:\> function Log-DebugSuperseded {'baz'}
PS C:\> Foo 'bar'
FOO: something
baz
PS C:\> Remove-Item Alias:\Log-Debug
PS C:\> Foo 'bar'
FOO: something
DEBUG: bar
PS C:\> _
```

---

**Edit:**

To make this work in a script you need to define both function and alias as global objects:

```
PS C:\> Get-Content .\test.ps1
Import-Module Deployment
Write-Host '--- without alias ---'
Foo 'bar'
function global:Log-DebugSuperseded {}
Set-Alias -Name Log-Debug -Value Log-DebugSuperseded -Scope global
Write-Host '--- with alias ---'
Foo 'bar'
PS C:\> ./test.ps1
--- without alias ---
FOO: something
DEBUG: bar
--- with alias ---
FOO: something
PS C:\> _
```

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy: I think I figured out a way. See updated answer.

Comment: When I read your answer, I thought you had it.  But in trying this morning, I cannot get it to work:  it will only work if I add the New-Alias command after the import of Logging (within Deployment.psm1) and not if I add it in the top level MyScript.ps1.  It feels like there is some kind of scoping/namespacing that is kicking in.  If I could figure out how to reference the funtion instance that was imported via the nested module import, then I would be golden...

Comment: You, sir, are a scholar!  Have some rep for your help... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try`Remove-Item` with the `function:` `PSDrive`.

```
Remove-Item function:Log-Debug
```

Comment: Fails with the error: Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'Function:\Log-Debug' because it does not exist.

Comment: Did you run that after you imported the module that you want to remove it from? Note that you should *not* have the backslash between the colon & function name.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: I'm using the Remove-Item, as given by you,  straight after the import.  The slash and colon are added by the error message.  Even if this succeeded, why would it work?  The code in Do-Something would be trying to call a method that no longer exists and surely thats not going to silently fail..